# Self Contained Linux Command line tool for converting text to doc, rtf, pdf

Tags: linux, command-line, self-contained

I'm looking for a command line tool for Linux that will allow me to convert UTF-8 plain text files to various formats. My problem is that I'm working on a secure company-specific flavour of Linux, so the tool can't rely on other packages, such as Open Office, being present. Does anyone know of such a tool?

Answer (score 0):

[Gnu a2ps](http://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/) allows you convert from anything to postscript (designed for printing). Not *exactly* what you want but if you have utilites to display postscript files, you can convert them into pdf.

Another option is [Gnu enscript](http://www.gnu.org/software/enscript/) which "converts text to Postscript, HTML or RTF with syntax highlighting". I'm not sure if it supports UTF-8.

Conversion into doc will be harder since it's a closed format. But I have in the past cheated by creating an HTML file with inline css and then renaming it to `.doc`. Worked back in the early 2000s. DOn't know about now.